# Large SVG picture causes page to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, svg

I use a big European map as SVG on a page on my Wordpress website.

When I insert it as `<img src="mysvg">` all things work properly, but I can't use jQuery with the svg paths.

jQuery works fine when I insert the `<svg>` tag directly, but because it's quite huge, about 386 lines of code, my wordpress crashes when I publish the page.

How can I fix this issue? Is there a way to have a shorter path coordinates?

Comment: 386 lines doesn't sound like very much at all. However, Wordpress is liable to mess up your SVG completely. I would consider writing a quick plugin to insert the SVG via a shortcode tag.

Comment: there is already a plugin, but if i insert the svg using a shortcode i don't have full access to manipulate the svg.

Comment: Why not? This doesn't make sense to me, sorry.

Comment: if i use the shortcode, it won't let me access the single paths with jquery...